# Is there a "Full Containment" option for databases in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server

In creating a new database on SQL Server 2014, the "Containment Type" dropdown in the create database dialog has only "None", and "Partial".  This kind of hints that there should be a "Full" option, but there isn't.

And, indeed, this article actually refers to both partially contained, and fully contained databases.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929071.aspx

Is there some SQL Server configuration option that I didn't select when installing SQL Server?  Or is there really just no actual "Fully Contained" option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support fully contained databases (yet).

Azure SQL databases are fully contained.